# How to get parent node's attribute value by using child node's attribute value in xmldocument?

Tags: c#, xml

I had xml like following:

```
   <Root Details="false">
      <Product count="45" Name="Success">
               <Source Id="123" Name="58372">
                 <Project Id="ABC" Level = "Good">
                   <Rest of the document/>
                 </Project>
              </Source>
               <Source Id="456" Name="83729">
                 <Project Id="DEF" Level = "Better">
                   <Rest of the document/>
                 </Project>
              </Source>
              <Source Id="789" Name="29832">
                 <Project Id="GHI" Level = "BAD">
                   <Rest of the document/>
                 </Project>
              </Source>
       </Product>
    </Root>
```

I need to get values of Source node's "Name" value by using Project node's "Id" attribute value. i.e. For Example If project id value is "GHI" then I need value "29832". Is there any way to get like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked into LINQ's XDocument and XElement classes? The code would be something like (I'm on my phone so doing this from memory):

var doc = XDocument.Load("your file.xml");
var sourceName = doc.Root.Elements("Project").Where(p => p.Attribute("Id").value == "GHI").First().Parent.Attribute("Name").value;

Every xelement has a parent property.